# JSON in EF Core and handle different JSON structure, superuser can configure different types but same table, best approach?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, entity-framework-core

C#, .NET Core and EF Core. I have a table that will handle activities. But different types can handle different types of child data and I want this types of activities to be configurable.

I have some ideas that I make a 'configtable' (parent+child) :

Parent table

```
int Id
string Name
List<child>
```

Child table (properties)

```
int Id
int ParentId
string PropertyName
string DisplayName
enum TypeOfProperty
..
```

Other data that needs for building form or table correctly.

In my activitytable :

```
int Id
int CreatorId
int OwnerId
string Name
int TypeOfActivityId
string Jsondata (and this column saves property and properties depends on TypeOfActivity)
```

I guess this approach could work?

But I can't use EF Core automatic handle of json data directly, I need to deserialize this json string by myself?

Anyone who can give me a hint how I can handle this string of jsondata and create a C# List<> that every row in the list contains all properties, the class origin properties and the properties in Jsondata (with help of my configure table)?

Comment: yes, you have to deserialize yourself.

Comment: That depends on the provider you use. e.g. if you are using postgres you don't have to serialize it yourself. Besides the serialization, it will also generate json related queries if you query over the json column.